# CMD return specific lines from piped input

Tags: cmd

Bored in class trying to figure this out.

On windows command prompt:

`ipconfig /all` return all the loopback, tunnel, etc.

if I run `ipconfig /all | find /n "Internal"` it will return [11]Ethernet Adapter Internal.  What I want to do is substring the 11 off the beginning and then pipe this to something else which will allow me to return lines 11-19 or whatever.  Can you do this in a single line similar to jquery and chaining?

Comment: You forgot the '/N' option in your code example.

Comment: correct the '/N' argument returns the specific line.  Any help regarding the rest of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple to parse out the 11 using a FOR /F loop. But making use of that value is difficult in a one liner from the command line.

Here is the best I could come up with for a one liner to run from the command line.

```
set "stop="&for /f "delims=[]" %N in ('ipconfig /all^|find /n "Internal"') do @for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %A in ('ipconfig /all^|findstr /n "^"') do @if %A geq %N if not defined stop echo(%B&>nul 2>nul set /a 1/(%A-%N-8)||set stop=1
```

The shortest one liner I could think of uses a different strategy.

```
set n=&for /f "delims=" %A in ('ipconfig/all') do @if defined n (set/a"1/n,n-=1">nul 2>&1&&echo %A) else echo %A|find "Internal"&&set n=8
```

But the above solution ignores blank lines.

If you want to preserve blank lines then the following works:

```
set n=&for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %A in ('ipconfig/all^|findstr/n "^"') do @if defined n (set/a"1/n,n-=1">nul 2>&1&&echo(%B) else echo %B|find "Internal"&&set n=8
```

**EDIT**

I shortened and simplified the logic of the 2nd and 3rd solutions a bit.

I'll try to explain the 2nd option:

I first explicitly undefine a counter and then use FOR to read the output of the IPCONFIG/ALL commmand. Now begins the fun part within the DO clause.

At first the counter is undefined so the ELSE clause is executed. I pipe the current line to FIND looking for "Internal". If the string is not found then nothing happens and we progress to the next line. But if it is found then the line is printed. Then the code after `&&` is executed since the string was found. There I set the counter to 8 because we want the next 8 lines printed.

The counter is defined for the remainder of the lines, so we now switch to the first part of the IF statement. I use SET /A to do some math. First I divide 1 by the current value of the counter. IF the counter is 0 then an error is raised and the rest of the statement is ignored. If the counter is not 0 then I next decrement the counter by 1. I redirect both stdout and stderr to nul because we don't want to see any messages from the SET /A command. If the SET command was successful, then I echo the line. Since I initially set the counter to 8 when the string was found, up to 8 lines will be printed before the counter reaches 0.

Comment: mother of god that is intense.  Anychance you could break down the 2nd one?